# Play Framework 2: Handle client disconnection in chunked response

Tags: java, asynchronous, playframework, playframework-2.1, chunked-encoding

I'm forwarding some real-time data to web clients using chunked encoding.

In the following way, I could make HTTP streaming responses,

```
public Result action() {
    return ok(new StringChunks() {
        public void onReady(final Out<String> out) {
            openStream().onData(new Consumer<String>() {
                public void accept(String string) {
                    out.write(string);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I need to clean up some resources after the client has disconnected. (by e.g. closing the browser window or when the stream reaches EOF)

When using WebSocket I could detect client disconnection using [Iteratee](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee).mapDone.

Is there an equivalent method to detect it when using [Chunks](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/api/java/play/mvc/Results.Chunks.html)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, just figured it out.

`Results.Chunked.Out<A>` object has `onDisconnected(Callback0)` method that I can register a disconnection callback. so

```
public Result action() {
    return ok(new StringChunks() {
        public void onReady(final Out<String> out) {
            out.onDisconnected(new F.Callback0() {
                public void invoke() throws Throwable {
                    // clean up things ...
                }
            }
            openStream().onData(new Consumer<String>() {
                public void accept(String string) {
                    out.write(string);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```